# while name mvc3 form with @Html.BeginForm() it display form fields between System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {} in explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in ASP.NET MVC3 and creating a form:

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmAcnt", id = "frmAcnt" })
```

Because I dont want to give action and controller name. It works fine but in Firefox or any other browser it shows form between these two lines. What can I do for remove it from display?

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm {

}
```

and in the page source this line is showing

```
<form action="/Home/AccCode" id="frmAcnt" method="post"     name="frmAcnt">System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm
```

below is my view

```
@model CBS.Models.AccntBD

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AccCode";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AccCode</h2>

<div>
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmAcnt", id = "frmAcnt" })
{

<table class="tablestyle">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" id="AcCode" name="AcCode" maxlength="10" placeholder="Account Code" autofocus="true" class="required" />

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
 <label>Description</label>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" id ="Descrip" name="Descrip" maxlength="150" placeholder="Desription..." class="Descrip"/>
                     </td>
</tr>

   <tr>
   <td>
   <span>

    <input type="button" name="clear" value="Cancel" onclick="clearForm(this.form);" >
   </span>

          <span>
                    <input type="submit" id="sve" name="action" value="Save" />
        </span>
         <span>
         <input type="button" id="edi" value="Edit" name="action"/>
                     </span>
   <span>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" id="del" name="action"/>     
</span>
</td>
<td>                                     
</td>     
</tr>   
<tr>      
<td>   
</td>
</tr>
</table>     
}
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your view for that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this once and ideally you can use `@using (Html.BeginForm()){ }` to define form

*View*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmAcnt", id = "frmAcnt" }))
{ 
  @* Your Form Content Here *@
}
```

*HTML* Output is

```
<form name="frmAcnt" method="post" id="frmAcnt" action="/"></form>
```

Comment: Which happened because you were using `Html.BeginForm` as astand-alone expression. It returns an object and you output it into the page, which calls `obj.ToString()`, which returns the class name by default. When you use `using` (as you should), the created form object never gets converted to string. So the only output you get is the direct response writes generated by the form's constructor and destructor.

Comment: you can also use Html.EndForm